# Entity Framework - Database.ExecuteSqlCommand - execute sql transaction command

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to execute SQL transaction command through `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`, but getting error when attempt commit transaction:

> The underlying provider failed on Commit.
>   System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException}
>
> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: connection
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Commit()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>   ... System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters) 
>   ...

```
internal partial class MyEntities
{
    public string BeginTrx(int levelIndex)
    {
        if (TrxList == null) TrxList = new Dictionary<int, MyTransactionScope>();

        var trxNm = GenRandomTrxNm();
        TrxList[levelIndex] = new MyTransactionScope(this, levelIndex, trxNm);

        var sql = string.Format("BEGIN TRAN {0}", trxNm);
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);

        return trxNm;
    }

    public Dictionary<int, MyTransactionScope> TrxList { get; protected set; }

    string GenRandomTrxNm()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        sb.Replace("-", "");
        sb.Insert(0, "T");

        if (sb.Length > 32) sb.Length = 32;

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public void RollbackTrx(int levelIndex)
    {
        var trxScope = TrxList[levelIndex];

        var sql = string.Format("ROLLBACK TRAN {0}", trxScope.TransactionName);
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);

        var newEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => (x.State != EntityState.Unchanged) && !trxScope.EntityEntries.Contains(x));

        foreach(var entry in newEntries)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }

        TrxList.Remove(levelIndex);
    }

    public void CommitTrx(int levelIndex)
    {
        var trxScope = TrxList[levelIndex];

        var sql = string.Format("COMMIT TRAN {0}", trxScope.TransactionName);
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, Database.Connection);

        TrxList.Remove(levelIndex);
    }
}

public class MyTransactionScope
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string TransactionName { get; set; }
    public List<DbEntityEntry> EntityEntries { get; set; }

    public MyTransactionScope(DbContext dbCntx, int level, string transactionName)
    {
        Level = level;
        TransactionName = transactionName;

        EntityEntries = dbCntx.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be much easier to use a `TransactionScope` in your C# code and put your database actions inside that transaction scope. [See MSDN documentation on `TransactionScope` for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: that was what I attempted, but still come up short. chk my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728142/how-to-create-nested-transactions-in-entity-framework-using-transactionscope

Comment: with SQL Server, there is no support for nested transaction - no matter how you try to create and use them.

Comment: i worked out a workaround to address my need of nested transaction https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d359652-d3ff-4127-bb94-c7bd40ba58c7/entity-framework-6-partially-using-transactionscope?forum=adodotnetentityframework